# Adding a button to an image view present in a stack view

Tags: ios, swift, stackview

I am trying to add a button to an image view which lies in a stack view. 
But whenever I try to add the button after adding the image view, the stack view gets divided into two parts, one housing the button and the other housing the image view.

I want to add an icon which is an image view, on top which there's a button which one clicked does the needful.

Comment: add the code that you currently have

Comment: I would suggest dont go for button. You can find out touch event on your added image & that would be more easy.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the button to the `stackView` and use background on that button to set the icon:

```
button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "icon"), for: .normal)
```

Or through storyboards select a button and set it in attributes inspector:

[image: Settings background image for button using storyboards]

Comment: I want to add the same via storyboard instead of code. Is there a way?

Comment: @vasudhaJha sure.. check updated answer for reference

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a button,
first add a uiview in place of button and then add image and button inside the uiview.